# What is the regex for the escaping []?

Tags: regex, vba, wildcard

I am trying to match square brackets i.e. [] in regex VBA in excel. I am trying with the below code but it is not working.

```
 Public Function IsSpecial(s As String) As Long
    Dim L As Long, LL As Long
    Dim sCh As String
    IsSpecial = 0
    For L = 1 To Len(s)
        sCh = Mid(s, L, 1)
        If sCh Like "[0-9a-zA-Z/;@%,'‚.+&/\(): ]" Or sCh = "_" Or sCh Like "[-]" Or sCh Like "\[" Then
        Else
            IsSpecial = 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next L
End Function
```

Comment: `Like` does not support regex, it supports wildcards only.

Comment: If sCh Like "[0-9a-zA-Z/;@%,'‚.+&/\(): ]" Or sCh = "_" Or sCh Like "[-]" Or sCh Like "\["   this is my actual condition and like is working fine, only the last OR condition is not working

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: Ok, just found, you need `Ch Like "[[]"`.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I've updated my question. Accordingly if the code finds [] it should return 0 but after using your above suggestion it is still returning 1

Comment: Ok, it seems regex is still a valid choice here as you need to check sequences of chars, not just individual chars.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Using the Like operator and wildcard characters in string comparisons](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-like-operator-and-wildcard-characters-in-string-comparisons-c472b6df-0d3e-4ffc-a21c-bb5721cc460a):

> You can use a group of one or more characters (charlist) enclosed in brackets (`[ ]`) to match any single character in expression, and charlist can include almost any characters in the ANSI character set, including digits. **You can use the special characters opening bracket (`[`), question mark (`?`), number sign (`#`), and asterisk (`*`) to match themselves directly only if enclosed in brackets.** You cannot use the closing bracket (`]`) within a group to match itself, but you can use it outside a group as an individual character.

So, you need to use

```vb
Ch Like "[[]"
```

However, the function you have is not following your logic, since it checks each char individually, and you want to make sure `[]` is checked as a char sequence.

With a regex, it will look like

```vb
Public Function IsSpecial(s As String) As Long
    Dim L As Long, LL As Long
    Dim rx As New regExp
    rx.Pattern = "^(?:[0-9a-zA-Z/;@%,'‚.+&/\\(): _-]|\[])*$"
    IsSpecial = 0
    If Not rx.Test(s) Then IsSpecial = 1
End Function
```

Comment: sorry i need to match both the opening and closing brackets not only any one of them

Comment: If the pattern is found then my code returns 0 as else it returns 1. Now my problem is that i also want to match [] (both of them opening and closing square brackets)

Comment: @newbie0007 It seems you want to check if there is `[]` substring in the input, right? But right now, you check each char individually.

Comment: yes correct, and after using your code Ch Like "[ [ ]" function is still returning 1 because your code is not matching the closing bracket

Comment: @newbie0007 It will be much simpler with a regex.

Comment: please tell how? if you could replace my whole if statement with a simpler regex which should include all the characters which i have

Comment: @newbie0007 Check the new function.

Comment: It is giving compile time error at line 3. It says user defined type not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230630/discussion-between-newbie0007-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: figured it out but it is still returning 1 for  [ ]

Comment: @newbie0007 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops. If you need to allow `[ ]`, add the space between `\[` and `]`